# C++ file i/o stream issue

Tags: c++, sorting, file-io

First of all I DO NOT WANT CODES  I want to write them myself but I am current out of idea for this part so any help would be appreciated  BUT I DO NOT WANT written ANY CODE

Here is the problem that I can't seem to solve.

okay I'm re-edit this to give you the questions.

Assuming we read the input from the ifstream (text file) and the system end of file condition signals end of input

- the first line is last name up to 20 char
- the second line is the person firs name up to 10 char
- the third line is the two character postal service abbreviation up to
  2 char
- the forth line is the company up to 40 char

the part I don't get is part of the error handing ...

- fewer or greater  four input lines per attendee would be rejected

how do we know when to stop for the greater or less than 4 input per- person?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Are there any separators between each "record." Say a blank line or some other convention?

Comment: yeah i tried it with string array a bunch of if statements and a counter and the file pointer method 

and they are separated  by a new line which is different between windows system and Linux and iOS

Comment: Requirement is not clear enough.

Comment: I can't understand this question at all.

Comment: Who says the second `james` is invalid? Couldn't it be the name of the company where the first `james` works?

Comment: @Beta: The state names would still be in the wrong places - I think that's what he's focused on.

Comment: yeah the state name would be at the wrong place hence we ignore the input

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde, @ricedragon: there's nothing wrong with a state name in "the wrong place", e.g. James Washington. The problem is when a non-state-name is where a state-name should be. If you think the second `james` should be invalid, you're not thinking things through.

Comment: @arunmu thats what i was given with ... i have no problem if it is seperate files or a speace between each input but this...

Answer (score 2):

The post is not completely clear, but with the given information this is what I came up with on the fly:

First make a container (array, vector, list, map, whatever) to hold the names of the States. You will need this to check if a series of entries is valid.

Now, you said entries (each individual record [ie name, name, state, company]) is separated by newlines. Using this information I would read in lines until you hit a blank line and store them into a container for temporary holding.

When you reach the new line (signaling a new record), check the temporary container. If it contains 4 strings (lines) and are in the order of: non-state, non-state, state, non-state; then consider it a valid record and store it in a permanent container and clear the temp container.

Continue this until you reach the end of the file.

Hope this helps and makes sense as you asked explicitly for no code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a bitmap of states:

```
bool state_bitmap[NUM_STATES];
```

Initialize it with all the states:

```
state_bitmap[hash_code ("state1")] = true;
state_bitmap[hash_code ("state2")] = true;
// ...
```

For each string read at a state position, make sure it is in the bitmap:

```
std::string state = read_state_from_file ();
if (!state_bitmap[hash_code (state)]
{
    // Not a state!
}
```

If the problem is about duplicate names, you can follow a similar approach.
Read each string and map it to a `bool`, if it is not already there in the map:

```
std::map<std::string, bool> names;

std::string name = read_next_name_from_file ();
if (!names[name])
{
    names[name] = true;
}
else
{
    // name already in map, do something about that.
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't to do with duplicate names, but with whether the name is found where a state is expected.